# Find common all values for 2 columns

Tags: python

I have below dataframe:

```
Name      class
John      1  
John      1 
Mayank    2  
Mayank    2  
Harshil   3   
Harshil   3  
Harshil   3
```

In this case the output would be like:
class

```
Name      class 
John       1     
Mayank     2
Harshil    3
```

Comment: Is it DataFrame or List or Dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick up the solution what you need.

**List**

```
data = [('John', 1), ('John',1), ('Mayank', 2), ('Mayank', 2), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3)]
data = list(set(data))
print (data)
```

> [('Mayank', 2), ('Harshil', 3), ('John', 1)]

**Dict**

```
data = [('John', 1), ('John',1), ('Mayank', 2), ('Mayank', 2), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3)]
data = {d[0]:d[1] for d in data}
print(data)
```

> {'John': 1, 'Mayank': 2, 'Harshil': 3}

**DataFrame**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('John', 1), ('John',1), ('Mayank', 2), ('Mayank', 2), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3), ('Harshil', 3)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','class']).set_index('name')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

> name         class
>   John         1
>   Mayank       2
>   Harshil      3